# Hide/Show Meta Tags ASP.NET Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, metadata

Hey so currently I am placing meta tags such as :

```
<meta name="WT.oss_r" content="<%= SearchNumberOfResults%>"/>
```

I was thinking of putting this in a `ASP:Panel` and setting visible to `true` or `false` depending on `SearchNumberOfResults` being `String.IsNullOrEmpty` but that puts div mark up in the `<head>` section which is not ideal..

Whats a good way to hide and show meta tags ?

Comment: Maybe you can use a literal control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string description;
```

page initialize:

```
HtmlMeta tag = new HtmlMeta();
tag.Name = "description";
tag.Content = description;
Header.Controls.Add(tag);
```

see this : [Using-Meta-Tags-with-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17368/Using-Meta-Tags-with-Master-Pages-in-ASP-NET)

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MetaKeywords="<%=SearchNumberOfResults%>" MetaDescription="This is my blog that focuses on ASP.NET." AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

---

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    Page.MetaDescription = "sample meta description";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your meta tag:

```
runat="server" id="xxx"
```

and in ASP.NET code

```
MyPanel.xxx.visible = false;
```

OR

```
xxx.visible = false;
```

I belive "panel" dont work in head section